# polynomial hash function java?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

whenever i try to generate an index value , i get many collisions at one index . Highest collisions at one index 300 and second highest is like 10. The problem i think is that if words are of length 1, 2, 3 . They usually result in the smaller powers and hence produce a smaller number. Resulting in it getting added to buckets where the number is small. Is there a poly function where this does not happen ? or could you help me fix this problem ?

```
public int GetHashCompress(String str ){
    int ply=0;
    double mathIt=0;
    int size = str.length();
    for(int j = 0 ; j< size ; j++){
        double x0 =  (double) str.charAt(j); 
        double firstStep = (int) Math.pow(31, (size-j))*x0;
        mathIt = mathIt + firstStep  ;      // hash function +1 to increance  the range to keep 33 to the power >1 

        }
    //arrayOfRawHash.add(mathIt); // this is for testing it later
    ply =(int) mathIt %numBucket;// this is where it is compressed 
    return ply; 

}
```

Comment: what about `String#hashCode()`? Or if you want a better hash, MD5, SHA1, .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my compression function. It works perfect with the MAD method of compression functions. 
Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

The [Jenkin's One-at-a-Time Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function#one-at-a-time) provides good avalanche behavior for small values and is very easy to code.

```
public static int oatHash(final String hashMe) {
    return oatHash(hashMe.getBytes());
}

public static int oatHash(byte[] hashMe) {
    int hash = 0;
    for (byte aHashMe : hashMe) {
        hash += aHashMe;
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Technically, this solution is linear, rather than polynomial, but a polynomial solution would imply that the algorithm doesn't read all the characters of your String.  If you're looking for "very fast" and "well distributed" rather than "polynomial", then this should fit your needs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your hash function collides because it's dreadful. 31^i for i = 0 to size, Basically every step of that is going to have i roots of base 31. 31, 31*31, 31*31*31, these aren't different prime numbers to stop collisions or a good avalanche cascade, and it's going to cost a fortune in time to do the power routine. These are all multiples of the same number over and over again.

```
 private static long hash(long v) {
        long hash = v;
        long h = hash;

        switch ((int) hash & 3) {
            case 3:
                hash += h;
                hash ^= hash << 32;
                hash ^= h << 36;
                hash += hash >> 22;
                break;
            case 2:
                hash += h;
                hash ^= hash << 22;
                hash += hash >> 34;
                break;
            case 1:
                hash += h;
                hash ^= hash << 20;
                hash += hash >> 2;
        }
        hash ^= hash << 6;
        hash += hash >> 10;
        hash ^= hash << 8;
        hash += hash >> 34;
        hash ^= hash << 50;
        hash += hash >> 12;
        return hash;
    }
```